# New line after array is appended with a value in Shell Script

Tags: arrays, bash

How to print $arr appended value in new line? Below is the code.

```
arr=() |
hive -e 'show tables in database'|
while read line
do
echo "The name of the line is $line"
  arr+="TABLE NAME : $line"
done
echo $arr
```

Comment: Something like `arr+="TABLE NAME : $line"$'\n'` ??

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues in the code.

1. Piping the assignment to an array makes no sense. The assignment has no output, so there's nothing to pipe.
2. `+=` without parentheses does a string concatenation, so only `${arr[0]}` gets changed. Use

   ```
   arr+=("TABLE NAME : $line")
   ```
3. Commands in a pipeline are running in subshells, which means the assignment only happens in a subshell, the array in the main shell is not updated. Use "process substitution" instead:

   ```
   while ...
   done < <(hive ...)
   ```

Also, I'd rather store just the table names in the array, as you can reuse the values later, instead of storing the whole messages. Fixing all these, we can get something like

```
#!/bin/bash
tables=()
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    echo "The name of the line is $line"
    tables+=("$line")
done < <(hive -e 'show tables in database')
printf 'TABLE NAME: %s\n' "${tables[@]}"
```

Comment: Instead of that `for` loop, we can use a single command: `printf 'TABLE NAME: %s\n' "${tables[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place for the [`mapfile` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile): reads the output of a command and stores each line as an array element. Useful with the process substitution here

```sh
mapfile -t arr < <(hive ...)

for elem in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "TABLE: $elem"
done
```

Comment: We could `printf 'TABLE: %s\n' "${arr[@]}"` instead of that loop.